# Angular - Checking if a field is empty

Tags: angularjs

Bit of a trivial one here however am new to Angular so excuse me.

Whenever I have an input field - I only want an action to occur if the field actually contains some valid content.

What i find I'm having to do is first instantiate a variable, then assign that to whatever input there is then do a boolean check in a if.

Is the the correct way to go around this? If i don't instantiate the variable (or don't use one at all) i run into getting `undefined` error:

```
var textToSearch = '';
textToSearch = $scope.main.searchInputField.trim();

if (textToSearch){
      $location.path('/search/'+textToSearch);
}
```

Also (on another note)
I'm sanitising everything on the server side however on Angular/client side is there a quick and easy function I can use?

Thanks

Comment: you can use a for loop to check every input field and check if input `ng-model` has value

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an ng-model for 'main.searchInputField' so if you want to check if the field is empty you can just write

```
$scope.main = {};
if($scope.main.searchInputField.trim().length > 0){
 //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have `ng-model` of input field 1 as `some.data` and input field 2 as `some.data1`

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.some.length;i++){
    if($scope.some[i]){
        //do something
     }
}
```

it will check every field.

Answer (score 0):

This is using Bootstrap for email validation, but the same logic applies if you are using your own classes.

```
<div ng-class="(emailRegExp.test(email) && email != null) ? 'has-success' : 'has-error'" class="form-group has-feedback">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
    </div>
    <input ng-model="email" ng-change="checkEnableSubmit()" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailStatus">
  </div>
  <span ng-class="(emailRegExp.test(email) && email != null) ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove'" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

The ng-class directive accomplishes the validation if:

1. The checkEnableSubmit() function in your controller only allows a submission when the data is valid (I would be happy to include that code, too)
2. Both classes in the ternary operator on line #1 indicate valid data and non-valid data (in this example one makes the input appear green and the other red)